# Summing Values From Meta Fields in PHP (Wordpress)

Tags: php, wordpress, math

I am trying to update a custom field by 'adding' a number from a front-end form to the existing number in the field.
The script I wrote is not adding the existing number, but just updating to the number entered in the form.

I think there needs to be some sort of conversion for what the get_post_meta function is returning, so the script understands it as a number.

The script is:

```
if(isset($_POST['Add_Work_Task'])){
    
    $Work_Required_Hours=$_POST['Work_Required_Hours'];
    $Parent_Work=$_POST['Work_Parent_TaskGroup'];
    $Current_Buried_Hours =get_post_meta( $Parent_Work, 'Work_Buried_Hours',true);

    $Total_Buried_Hours= $Current_Buried_Hours + $Work_Required_Hours;

    $Buried_Required_Hours= array('Work_Buried_Hours' => $Total_Buried_Hours);
            wp_update_post(array(
                                        'ID'        => $Parent_Work,
                                        'meta_input'=> $Buried_Required_Hours,
                                ));
    
}
```

I also tried

```
$Total_Buried_Hours= (float)$Current_Buried_Hours + (float)$Work_Required_Hours;

$Total_Buried_Hours= floatval($Current_Buried_Hours) + floatval($Work_Required_Hours);

$Total_Buried_Hours= $Current_Buried_Hours += $Work_Required_Hours;

$Total_Buried_Hours= print_r($Current_Buried_Hours) + $Work_Required_Hours; this one adds 1 only.
```

and

```
$Current_Buried_Hours =implode(".",get_post_meta( $Parent_Work, 'Work_Buried_Hours',true));
```

To narrow it down I know for a fact the problem is with the get_post_meta function, I have tested adding the $_POST twice and it worked like the following:

```
$Total_Buried_Hours= $Work_Required_Hours + $Work_Required_Hours;
```

Comment: Are u 100% sure that you will always get a floating value out of get_post_meta? W7o knowing what data are you trying to add it's hard to tell where's the problem

Comment: @Diego I am trying to add normal numbers, like 1+1=2.

I am not sure about the floating value, but I know that the problem is with what get_post_meta is returning, because if I remove it and add a normal number it works.

However, I tried applying the floatval() function on what is returned by the get_post_meta, but it still didn't work.

Comment: Have you tried var_dump($Current_Buried_Hour) to know exactly what you're working with. If so can you provide the information from the var_dump

Comment: @David_2002 Hi David, thank you for your comment. I tried the var_dump before but it also didn't work.
I made it work simply by putting parentheses around the whole equation ($Work_Required_Hours + $Work_Required_Hours)   but I don't understand what difference that made. 

I will wait to see if there is a better theoretical explanation as to why this is happenning. otherwise I will just submit it as an answer although I don't quite understand why